# Coffescript and multiple arguments

Tags: coffeescript

I can't see where is the **syntax** problem here :

```
x = ()->new TranformService()
angular.module('rcMovable').factory (  "transformService", x)
```

When there is no problem there

```
x = ()->new TranformService()
angular.module('rcMovable').factory  "transformService", x
```

Forget about Angular stuff for the moment, I have `:2:58: error: unexpected ','`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put a space between a method name and the parenthesis used to invoke it. If you do, the parenthesis are no longer part of the function invocation, they're for order-of-operations on the arguments to the function.

Consider a few examples of valid and invalid syntax:

- `x()` is a valid invocation with no arguments
- `x ()` is an *invalid* invocation of `x` with *one argument*: `()`. Because `()` is not a valid expression, this is a syntax error.
- `x (name: "bob")` or `x (->3 * 3), 4` are both valid invocations, because the `(...)` is a valid expression
- `x(a, b)` is again a valid invocation of `x` with two arguments
- `x (a, b)` is an *invalid* invocation of `x` with *one argument*: `(a, b)`. Again, `(a, b)` is not itself a valid expression, so this is a syntax error.

In your case, you're trying to invoke `.factory` with one argument: `("transformService", x)`, which is not a valid expression.

What you've written is essentially this:

```
a = ("transformSerice", x) # invalid syntax
factory(a)
```